# Euler Representation of the factorial

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, factorial, gamma-function

I know that Euler proved that

$\displaystyle z! = \int_{0}^{1} \left(- \ln\left(t\right)\right)^z dt$

How can this be proven?

Comment: Do you want to know how it was proven at the time with the theorems available then or how to prove it in modern times?

Comment: Induction and integration by parts, maybe? Would that work?

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin How to prove it in modern times using modern methods

Answer (score 0):

With definition of Gamma function
$$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}\ dt$$
let $e^{-t}=u$ then
$$\Gamma(x)=\int_1^0 u(-\ln u)^{x-1}\dfrac{-1}{u} du$$
and so
$$x!=\Gamma(x+1)=\int_0^1 (-\ln u)^{x} du$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got to the second equation from the definition of the gamma function.

Comment: If $e^{-t}=u$ then $t = - \log u$. Also $\frac{du}{dt} = - e^{-t}$ so $- e^t du = dt = -e^{- \log u} du =- e^{\log 1/u} du = -du/u$